# compare ImageView and a drawable picture a pointing to the same picture

Tags: android, imageview, drawable

how can I test that img1 and R.drawable.picture_1  point to the same picture ?

I tried this but I am printing "NOT OK" instead of ok

```
    ImageView img1  = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);  
    img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.picture_1);      

    if(R.drawable.picture_1 ==img1.getId())  
    {  
    log.error("OK");  
    }else{  
    log.error("NOT OK");  
    }
```

Comment: yes indeed but it was never responded

Comment: What do you mean? The question I linked has an accepted answer and multiple alternatives.

Comment: sorry it works, I only checked the last answer which was wrong, many thanks !!